# Cannot override Kestrel RequestSizeLimit in aspnet core

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

In asp.net core 2 a breaking changed was added that limits the request size to 30 mb ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/267)).

In that article, a solution is provided if you would like to overrule the 30 mb limit. This is supposed to be done by adding an attribute to the action like so:

```
[HttpPost]
[RequestSizeLimit(100_000_000)]
public IActionResult MyAction([FromBody] MyViewModel data)
{
```

When I do this, and rebuild my project, I still get the following errors in Kestrel:

```
 An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Request body too large.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame.ThrowRequestRejected(RequestRejectionReason reason)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.ForContentLength.OnReadStart()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.TryInit()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.<ReadAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.FrameRequestStream.<ReadAsyncInternal>d__21.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.BufferedReadStream.<EnsureBufferedAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReaderStream.<ReadAsync>d__36.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.StreamHelperExtensions.<DrainAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReader.<ReadNextSectionAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.<InnerReadFormAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenStore.<GetRequestTokensAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgery.<ValidateRequestAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter.<OnAuthorizationAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.<Invoke>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.<Invoke>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[0]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Request body too large.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame.ThrowRequestRejected(RequestRejectionReason reason)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.ForContentLength.OnReadStart()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.TryInit()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.<ReadAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.FrameRequestStream.<ReadAsyncInternal>d__21.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.BufferedReadStream.<EnsureBufferedAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReaderStream.<ReadAsync>d__36.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.StreamHelperExtensions.<DrainAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReader.<ReadNextSectionAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.<InnerReadFormAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenStore.<GetRequestTokensAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.DefaultAntiforgery.<ValidateRequestAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter.<OnAuthorizationAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.<Invoke>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.<Invoke>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[17]
      Connection id "0HL7KFNC938GT" bad request data: "Request body too large."
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Request body too large.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame.ThrowRequestRejected(RequestRejectionReason reason)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.ForContentLength.OnReadStart()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.TryInit()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.<ConsumeAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame`1.<ProcessRequestsAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
infoinfo: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 161.172ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8
: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[17]
      Connection id "0HL7KFNC938GT" bad request data: "Request body too large."
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Request body too large.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame.ThrowRequestRejected(RequestRejectionReason reason)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.ForContentLength.OnReadStart()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.TryInit()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.<ConsumeAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Frame`1.<ProcessRequestsAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 161.172ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:55567/ExtensionSpecifiedQuotation/Step5 multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryDbXL0DpRU4KQtqMM 44622809
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:55567/ExtensionSpecifiedQuotation/Step5 multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryDbXL0DpRU4KQtqMM 44622809
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action MyRedactedProject.Controllers.ExtensionSpecifiedQuotationController.Step5 (MyRedactedProject) in 0.6059ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action MyRedactedProject.Controllers.ExtensionSpecifiedQuotationController.Step5 (MyRedactedProject) in 0.6059ms
```

This is my Program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

}
```

And this is in my Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // For more details on using the user secret store see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
            builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();
        }

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<MailSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("MailSettings"));

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddDbContext<MyExampleContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        // Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache.
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        });

        services.AddMvc(options => 
                    options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute()));

        // allow razor-to-string for mailer
        services.AddScoped<IViewRenderService, ViewRenderService>();

        // enable nodejs in .net core
        services.AddNodeServices();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, MyExampleContext context)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            //app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSession();

        string culture = "nl-NL";

        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture),
            SupportedCultures = new [] {new CultureInfo(culture) },
            SupportedUICultures = new [] { new CultureInfo(culture) }
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=ExtensionBasicQuotation}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        DbInitializer.Initialize(context);
    }
}
```

Is there anything missing? The way I read it, adding the attribute to the action should be sufficient, however Kestrel still returns a Request body too large error.

Adding the `[DisableRequestSizeLimit]` attribute instead of the RequestSizeLimit one also generates the same error.

The project is on Microsoft.AspNetCore.All version 2.0.0.

Comment: It looks like DefaultAntiforgery is reading the request body before your new limit is applied. That ordering isn't right. Please open a bug at https://github.com/aspnet/mvc/issues

Comment: @Tratcher thanks! Done: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6777